# Application Error in Explorer.exe on shutdown

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, shutdown

Sometimes when I shut down Windows 8.1 I get the following error message:

> #### explorer.exe - Application Error
>
> The instruction at *memory address* referenced memory at *memory address*. The memory could not be read.
>
> Click on OK to terminate the program.

[image]

It disappears on its own, and everything seems fine, but it is a little odd.

I found [KB2929203](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2929203) on Microsoft's website which states "The error does not harm the computer, and it can be safely ignored." It also adds that the error message is the direct result of using "right-click the Start tip" to shut down Windows...

[image: Shut down menu]

...and that a workaround is to use the "Charms" method to shutdown your computer.

According to Microsoft, "This error occurs because the Explorer.exe process accesses memory that has already been freed during the shutdown process."

Isn't there any fix for this? It seems crazy to get a big ugly error every time I shut down my PC using the fastest method.

Comment: Is Windows 8.1 a clean install? Do you get the same issue if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)? In case you have pre-built computer, what's the exact model?

Comment: No, Windows 8.1 was an inplace upgrade to a clean install of Windows 8. I'll attempt a clean boot.

Comment: this is no fix for this. Maybe the August Update fixes it. If this is urgent, phone the Microsoft support

Comment: @magicandre1981 Do you think Microsoft telephone support will have a fix for this?

Comment: when they tracked the issue down to accessing invalid memory they should be also able to fix this.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Over the phone...?

Comment: try it and see what they can do.